# Sum of series & sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, summation

I dont know how to evaluate the first one, for second one I can only show the sum is less than 2.
$$\begin{align}
  & \prod\limits_{k=4}^{\infty }{\left( 1-{{\left( \frac{3}{k} \right)}^{3}} \right)} \\ 
 & \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\sin \left( \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \right)} \\ 
\end{align}$$

Comment: You shouldn't be able to show that because the sum diverges clearly via small-angle approximations. For the first one, just take the exponential of its logarithm.

Comment: @YonatanN Sry, I got a typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a result by maple for the infinite product

$$\prod\limits_{k=4}^{\infty }{\left( 1-{{\left( \frac{3}{k} \right)}^{3}} \right)} = {\frac {8}{15561\,\pi}}\,{ {\cosh \left( \frac{3\pi \,\sqrt {3}}{2} \right) 
}}. $$

**Added:** The numerical sum of the series evaluated by maple

$$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\sin \left( \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \right)} \sim 1.817928721 $$

Comment: Thx, but how to evaluate the first one? :)